# Portrait images not working with css slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, for my portfolio i used an image slider called wow slider
http://wowslider.com/

on my site
http://jackmurdock.site50.net/StudioWork.html

I have several galleries the combine portrait and landscape images and they work, yet on the "studio work" page (under photograpy) the portrait images refuse to display correctly.  The one at the beginning works fine but the last few are all sideways.

The image behavior is controlled by this css

```
/*
 *  generated by WOW Slider 5.6
 *  template Elemental
 */

#wowslider-container1 { 
    zoom: 1; 
    position: relative; 
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto 0px;
    z-index:90;
    border:none;
    text-align:left; /* reset align=center */
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 340px;
    left: 250px;

}
* html #wowslider-container1{ width:1000px }
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images ul{
    position:relative;
    width: 10000%; 
    height:auto;
    left:0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-spacing:0;
    overflow: visible;
    /*table-layout:fixed;*/
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images ul li{
    width:1%;
    line-height:0; /*opera*/
    float:left;
    font-size:0;
    padding:0 0 0 0 !important;
    margin:0 0 0 0 !important;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_images{
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images a{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    color:transparent;
}
#wowslider-container1 img{
    max-width: none !important;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images img{
    width:100%;
    border:none 0;
    max-width: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#wowslider-container1 a{ 
    text-decoration: none; 
    outline: none; 
    border: none; 
}

#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets { 
    font-size: 0px; 
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:70;
}
#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets div{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
#wowslider-container1  .wsl{
    display:none;
}
#wowslider-container1 sound, 
#wowslider-container1 object{
    position:absolute;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_photoItem {
    border: 2em solid #fff;
    margin-left: -2em;
    margin-top: -2em;
}


#wowslider-container1 {
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAQAAADZc7J/AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAABwSURBVEjH7ZJBEsAgCAMT/v/n9NCOSqe2oD2yNx1JggB4BCEFWyFASP2KMQE7ywWhe/tTRGCGogLk02tFctiW/SUgaMyQG4PdPzDn31rQbMb8FiAXgvsEJNax1yVlVGAjA93apP3HFhZTGIqiKH7iADB6HxPlHdNVAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0ZQAyMDE0LTA3LTA3VDEzOjQ5OjEwKzAyOjAwm7WiFAAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAxNC0wNy0wN1QxMzo0OToxMCswMjowMOroGqgAAAAASUVORK5CYII="), move;
}
#wowslider-container1.grabbing {
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAQAAADZc7J/AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAABaSURBVEjH7ZMxCkAhDEOT8u9/5TpJ+xWkFse8IYutJgEB8RCHL1qCc90BEFnT6QH7mwgFHBUf8wJyS1TDLuc3vmighx37LZdIth3E5hKj9n6O0HRh+oJCiFcMxRUUDxR1CTMAAAAldEVYdGRhdGU6Y3JlYXRlADIwMTQtMDctMDdUMTM6NDk6MzgrMDI6MDDqf+sOAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOm1vZGlmeQAyMDE0LTA3LTA3VDEzOjQ5OjM4KzAyOjAwmyJTsgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="), move;
}
#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets { 
    padding: 9px; 
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a { 
    width:11px;
    height:11px;
    background: url(./bullet.png) left top;
    float: left; 
    text-indent: -4000px; 
    position:relative;
    margin-left:5px;
    color:transparent;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a:hover{
    background-position: 0 50%;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a.ws_selbull{
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_next, #wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-2em;
    z-index:60;
    height: 4.5em;
    width: 4.5em;
    background-image: url(./arrows.png);
    opacity: 0.8;   
    background-size: 200%;
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_next{
    background-position: 100% 0;
    right:2.1em;
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev {
    left:2.1em;
    background-position: 0 0; 
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_next:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}  

/*playpause*/
#wowslider-container1 .ws_playpause {
    display:none;
    width: 4.5em;
    height: 4.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2em;
    margin-top: -2em;
    z-index: 59;
    background-size: 100%;
}

#wowslider-container1:hover .ws_playpause {
    display:block;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_pause {
    background-image: url(./pause.png);
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_play {
    background-image: url(./play.png);
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_pause:hover, #wowslider-container1 .ws_play:hover {
    background-position: 100% 100% !important;
}/* bottom center */
#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets {
    bottom: 0px;
    left:50%;
}
#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets div{
    left:-50%;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws-title{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    bottom: 1.7em;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0.9em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0.9em; 
    padding:0.8em;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    color:#5D5D5D;
    z-index: 50;
    font-family:'Open Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    border-radius:0.5em;
    -moz-border-radius:0 1em 1em 0;
    border-radius:0 1em 1em 0;   
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=90); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #5D5D5D;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #5D5D5D; 
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws-title div{
    padding-top:0.25em;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws-title span{
    font-size: 1.8em;
}#wowslider-container1 .ws_images ul{
    animation: wsBasic 35.1s infinite;
    -moz-animation: wsBasic 35.1s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: wsBasic 35.1s infinite;
}
@keyframes wsBasic{0%{left:-0%} 5.7%{left:-0%} 11.11%{left:-100%} 16.81%{left:-100%} 22.22%{left:-200%} 27.92%{left:-200%} 33.33%{left:-300%} 39.03%{left:-300%} 44.44%{left:-400%} 50.14%{left:-400%} 55.56%{left:-500%} 61.25%{left:-500%} 66.67%{left:-600%} 72.36%{left:-600%} 77.78%{left:-700%} 83.48%{left:-700%} 88.89%{left:-800%} 94.59%{left:-800%} }
@-moz-keyframes wsBasic{0%{left:-0%} 5.7%{left:-0%} 11.11%{left:-100%} 16.81%{left:-100%} 22.22%{left:-200%} 27.92%{left:-200%} 33.33%{left:-300%} 39.03%{left:-300%} 44.44%{left:-400%} 50.14%{left:-400%} 55.56%{left:-500%} 61.25%{left:-500%} 66.67%{left:-600%} 72.36%{left:-600%} 77.78%{left:-700%} 83.48%{left:-700%} 88.89%{left:-800%} 94.59%{left:-800%} }
@-webkit-keyframes wsBasic{0%{left:-0%} 5.7%{left:-0%} 11.11%{left:-100%} 16.81%{left:-100%} 22.22%{left:-200%} 27.92%{left:-200%} 33.33%{left:-300%} 39.03%{left:-300%} 44.44%{left:-400%} 50.14%{left:-400%} 55.56%{left:-500%} 61.25%{left:-500%} 66.67%{left:-600%} 72.36%{left:-600%} 77.78%{left:-700%} 83.48%{left:-700%} 88.89%{left:-800%} 94.59%{left:-800%} }

#wowslider-container1 .ws_images  img{
    border-radius: 4px; 
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;

}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_effect img{
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets  a img{
    text-indent:0;
    display:block;
    bottom:20px;
    left:-34px;
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    max-width:none;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a:hover img{
    visibility:visible;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_bulframe div div{
    height:48px;
    overflow:visible;
    position:relative;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bulframe div {
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:68px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets .ws_bulframe{
    display:none;
    bottom:18px;
    overflow:visible;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bulframe span{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px;
    margin-left:-6px;
    left:34px;
    background:url(./triangle.png);
    width:15px;
    height:6px;
}
```

The app scales all images to whatever resolution you chose.  The one at the beginning is 700x1000 as are the ones towards the end that dont seem to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If someone is able to solve this issue for me, i will send them $5 via pay pal.

Answer (score 0):

The images themselves are sideways. You need to rotate them on your own computer and re-upload them. Even basic photo viewers like paint have the ability to rotate images.

Here is the direct link to one of your images, for example: http://jackmurdock.site50.net/data1/images/dsc_8513.jpg

Since the direct link is also rotated, it just proves that it is not caused by the slider or any HTML/css markup.

Comment: I tried doing this. I rotated the images so they are all stand up
http://i61.tinypic.com/15x5mpx.jpg
But the images still come out sideways when viewed online.